# Javascript: Saving numbers to a variable after a string

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the numbers after these 3 strings ( TTT, RDT and PRPR ) and before the '?' sign.

Example URLS:

```
1.) http://www.website3.com/pages/coupon5+TTT1?adaafaf124ac
2.) http://www.website3.com/pages/coupon5+RDT12?aaacaf12c212
3.) http://www.website3.com/pages/coupon5+PRPR300?t222
```

example variables:

1. x = 1
2. x = 12
3. x = 300

   ```
    var path = http://www.website3.com/pages/coupon5+TTT1?adaafaf124ac;
    var newpath = path.match((TTT|RDT|PRPR)\d+).substring(/d+);
   ```

Comment: The + sign renders different in browsers. It would be better to get the numbers after these specific strings. ( TTT, RDT, PRPR ) - updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below statement will get the number between the plus sign and the question mark sign.

```
var path = 'http://www.website3.com/pages/coupon5+TTT1?adaafaf124ac';

var number_x =  path.match(/\+.+\?/)[0].match(/\d+/)[0] * 1;
```

---

If you wish to match the string with TTT/RDT/PRPR then use the below statement.

```
var number_x = path.match(/(TTT.+|RDT.+|PRPR.+)\?/)[0].match(/\d+/)[0] * 1
```

Comment: updated the answer, which tries to match with TTT/RDT/PRPR;

Comment: The URL is not hard coded but is taken from the window..would that make this not work?

Comment: Thanks! Your the best!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you both the vendors and the number after.

```
var path = 'http://www.website3.com/pages/coupon5+TTT1?adaafaf124ac';

var pathComponents = path.match(/(TTT|RDT|PRPR)([\d]+)\?/);

console.log(pathComponents[0]) \\ 'TTT1?' ---- Everything

console.log(pathComponents[1]) \\ 'TTT' ---- Vendor

console.log(pathComponents[2]) \\ '1' ---- Number(s)
```

This is in the case that your vendors are limited to TTT, RDT, and PRPR.

Comment: The plus sign renders differently in browers so I would prefer not to use that in the matching.

Comment: This does not use the plus sign and I do not understand what is breaking for you.